# How can i rewrite the views table output for endless scroll

Tags: views, theming

I use the module views load more and for an horizontal infinite scroll i want only one row with many columns. When i click on the load more button, views rendered every new page as a table. Like this:

```
<div class="view-content">
  <table>... 1. Page ...</table>
  <table>... 2. Page ...</table>
</div>
```

I try to rewrite the views-view--VIEWNAME.tpl.php and the views-view-grid--VIEWNAME.tpl.php but when i reduce this i get a output. Like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    ... 1. Page ...
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    ... 2. Page ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I reduce the views-view-grid--VIEWNAME.tpl.php to:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns): ?>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item): ?>
      <td <?php if ($column_classes[$row_number][$column_number]) { print 'class="' . $column_classes[$row_number][$column_number] .'"';  } ?>>
        <?php print $item; ?>
      </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and add the table and tr tags to the views-view--VIEWNAME.tpl.php.

Don`t know where the tbody tag comes. Same Problem here:
https://drupal.org/comment/4641640#comment-4641640

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module [Views Infinite Scroll](https://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll). It will help to integrate  jquery.autopager plugin with your drupal website.

> Views Infinite Scroll provides a Pluggable pagers that enables views infinite scrolling ( autopaging, depaging, endless pages ...you name it) by using jquery.autopager plugin. using this module with views page display will load another page whenever the user reaches bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, I want rewrite the views output for horizontal scroll. Views Infinity Scroll works only for vertical scrolling.

Comment: see this comment https://drupal.org/comment/6204150#comment-6204150